# Price set is required but “-none-” option remains

Tags: civimember

As the title says, we have a price set - its required, but the none option remains. This is being used for a membership sign up contribution page. Sorry I did not clarify earlier.

Civi 5.1, wordpress 4.9

Update: we ended up creating a new price set, making the options required, and a new contribution page and it all worked out.

Comment: Are you able to provide more information? Are you talking about on a contribution page?

Comment: Can you provide more information like what sort of price set are you using? Are you referring to quick config price set created through contribution page? Adding screenshot to support your question would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @themak - rather than updating the question can you post your solution as an answer and accept it - or remove the question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid such behavior is to write [`hook_civicrm_buildForm`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) and use contribution page id as a trigger in if condition and use jQuery to remove 'None' option from dropdown/radio.

Comment: Can you explain how implementing this hook would answer the question and provide an example of how this would be achieved?